# Property of a function and its second derivative

Tags: calculus

If $f(x)$ is a function and it's second derivative $f''(x)$ is continuous in a region around  $x=c$ and  $f''(c)<0$ then can we assume  that $f''(x)<0$ is also true in some open region, say $(a,b)$ around $x=c$ i.e $a<c<b$.

If the above statement is true how can I prove that.I need better explanation.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the second derivative: If $g$ is continuous at $c$ and $g(c) < 0$, then there is a neighbourhood $(a,b)$ of $c$ such that $g(x) < 0$ for all $x\in (a,b)$.

Comment: @Prahlad He edited the question - I was confused too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is true. Let $$f''(c) = L.$$ Then, $$V =\left(\frac{1}{2} L, \frac{3}{2} L\right)$$ is a neighborhood about $L$ of radius $\frac{1}{2} L$. By continuity, there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $c$ that $$f''(U) \subseteq V.$$ If $x \in U$, then, $f''(x) \in V$. But, $L<0$ so that $f''(x) <0$.

Comment: What if the function is continuous around $c$ but not necessarily *at* $c$? What about $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
|x| & \mathrm{for}\; x\neq0\\
-1 & \mathrm{for}\; x=0
\end{cases}$$ maybe it's just a stupid question as I've been away from calculus for a long time, but that function is continuous everywhere except at $x=0$, but it is continuous *around* $x=0$, is it not? (Also, a derivative of differentiable function need not be continuous.)

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say $f''(x)$. I know my example may not be the second derivative of any $f$, but it was just a crude example to illustrate my line of thought.

Comment: This isn't possible, because the question states that $f''(c) < 0$, implying that $f''(c)$ is defined. But it would be the same concept, except $V$ would be a deleted neighborhood of $L$ (e.g. $V= N^*(L, \frac{1}{2} L)$.

Comment: Suppose that $f''$ is not defined at $c$ but $\lim_{x \to c} f''(x) < 0$. Then, there would exist a deleted neighborhood $U^*$ of $c$ so that $f(U^*) \subseteq V^*$, providing the same conclusion. Here, $V* = N*(L, \frac{1}{2} L)$ as stated above.

Comment: That's not what I'm saying. I say there might exist a function whose second derivative is continuous *everywhere* except at one point, call it $c$, **where** $f′′(c)<0$. I propose further that $f′′(x)≥0$ for every $x≠0$. How can you guarantee that no such function exists? $f''(c)$ may very well exist, and be negative, but there do exist functions whose derivatives are *not* continuous everywhere, and thus there *might* be a function whose discontinuity is at $x=c$, but $f(c)$ might exist and be negative. How can you guarantee that function doesn't exist?

Comment: I thought about this, and perhaps you are right. With what I know, I cannot prove it one way or another - I leave it the more knowledgeable Math.SE users to provide an answer to your comment. Note that the original question does not say that $f''$ is discontinuous at $x=c$.

Comment: But the original question doesn't say it *is* continuous at $x=c$, only *around* it.

Comment: The question says continuous in a region $(a, b)$ around $c$, i.e. $a < c < b$. The notation the OP is using gives inclusion to $c$ (as far as I understand).

Comment: That is in regards to the *question*. The OP asks "does there exist a region $(a,b)$ such that...maybe I'm grasping at straws here but I'm still a firm believer that the proposition is false :s I'm not trying to be argumentative--I think your answer is great I'm just still concerned about the possibility of an isolated discontinuity at $x=c$ in $f''$.

Comment: I agree and completely understand your view. Only the author can clarify the original intent of the question. My belief is that the region $(a, b)$ includes $c$. I would suggest leaving an alternative answer and letting the author decide which of our interpretations is correct. I also edited my answer to make the neighborhood more precise.

Comment: I suppose it is just minor semantics. I would bet that the OP intends for $f''$ to be continuous *at* $c$ as well! But my previous real analysis instructors have been *so* picky, so I *never* assume anything :o)

Comment: Oh, I've had one of those too. No worries - better safe than sorry. Merry Christmas! :-)

Comment: And merry Christmas to you too!

Answer (score 0):

It is true if $f''$ is continuous **at** and around $c$, not *just* around $c$:

recall
$$\mathrm{sgn}(x)=\begin{cases}
-1 & x<0,\\
0 & x=0,\\
1 & x>0.
\end{cases}$$

Now let $$g(t)=\int_{\beta}^{t}\mathrm{(sgn}(s^{2})-0.5)ds,$$

and let $$f(x)=\int_{\alpha}^{x}g(t)dt,$$

so, by the fundamental theorem of calculus, $$f'(x)=g(x)=\int_{\beta}^{x}\mathrm{(sgn}(s^{2})-0.5)ds,$$

which means $$f''(x)=g'(x)=\mathrm{sgn}(x^{2})-0.5.$$

We have that $f(x)$ is continuous everywhere and $f''(x)$ is continuous everywhere except at $x=0$. Note further that $f''(0)=-0.5<0$. We see that, for all $x\in\mathbb{R}\backslash  \{0\}$, we have $f''(x)>0$. So there is no open neighborhood $S=(a,b)$ around $0$ such that $f(y)<0$ whenever $y\in S$, since $f''(x)>0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}\backslash \{0\}$. Notice that the integrals all exist because the set of discontinuities of the $\mathrm{sgn}$ function on any compact set is of measure zero (there is only one discontinuity).

And so we require continuity *at* $c$ as well as around $c$.

If the other, more experienced members here at MSE could point out a flaw in my argument, please do, and I will [eventually] delete my answer.